# Using R to change the extension of all files in a folder

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have a folder with a huge amount of old `.xls` files. I would like R to turn the whole folder (change the extension) into `.csv` or `.xlsx` files to subsequently load them into r.

I have been using R for a while, but never like this, so I do not really have an idea where to start.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Various packages can read `xls` files.  Changing the extension doesn't convert the file into a different format.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did not realise that changing the extension does not change the format.

Comment: For `.csv` it does seem to work I noticed..

Comment: Not exactly - Excel can open an `.xls` file renamed to `.csv`  because it's sophisticated and can detect the correct structure of the data *despite* the incorrect extension.  But the file has definitely not been converted into that format.  It won't work in R or in pretty much any other software.

Comment: Very clear, thank you!